# How to change color system for all components in Antd?

Tags: reactjs, vite, antd

i’m trying to customize the whole color theme for my app components (using antd), i found that i can use  but i think it works only when i use it to surround my component (e.x. buttons)

What i want to ask about is, is there any way to modify the color configuration in the whole app so whenever i insert a new component it appears with my customized colors directly?
I don’t want to use ConfigProvider in multiple places..

Note: i noticed that in Theme Editor provided by antd, i can save the new color system i made and i can export it as json file, but I don’t know how to use it and where?

I use React with Vite

I tried the Theme Editor provided by Antd, but I didn’t know how to use it?

I tried the  thing but it’s annoying to use it all over my components

```
<ConfigProvider
theme={{
    token: {
        colorPrimary: '#8993ED',
    }
 }}
>
<Button className="nav--login" type="primary">Login</Button>
</ConfigProvider>
```

i need a way to modify the configs in a single place so then i can use components with the new customized colors as i want

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.